# Is there any way to label dummy variable in Excel?

Tags: excel

The following column contains a dummy variable for gender:

```
gender
1
0
2
0
```

where `1 is male`, `2 is female`, `0 is unknown`.

I want to assign labels to the values, like in `Stata`, so that when I construct a chart, the legend would show `Male` instead of `1`. Also, it would be nice if the dataset depicted string `Male`, but assumed value `1` for calculations.

How can I do that?

Comment: This question does not seem to be programming-related (although it may be if you revise it a bit), recommend to move it to Superuser.  You'll want to provide some more information, e.g., screen shots/images of the existing charts, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not (as far as I know) supported in Excel. What you need is sort of an ID value and a display value as is commonly known from DB-oriented controls like a Listbox in Access or the like. This does not exist in a single Excel cell, you'd have to simply make another column or replace the values.

*BUT...*

In this specific case you could reach the goal with the following 'hack':
The cells' `numberformat` supports different format strings for positive and negative values and for 0. For your three-valued-logic, you could make use of that, but you'd have to change your IDs to 1, 0 and -1. Then use `"Male";"Female";"Unknown"` as a custom format string.
... if this does not work, rather use a seperate column with a simple formula.